# Child entity data loss in many to many relationship hibernate

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

Below are many many relationship where users are save into users table and also there is entry in user_role table but entry added in the role table has name field value missing ?

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Users implements Serializable {
    @Id
    String id;

    String username;
    String password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Table(name = "role")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
}

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaDynamicQueryRepository<Users, String> {
}


public void save(){
Users users = new Users();
        users.setUsername("ui-user");
        users.setPassword("ui1234");
        users.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        Role adminRole = Role.builder()
                .name("ui-role")
                .build();

        Role testRole = Role.builder()
                .name("ui-test-role")
                .build();

        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(adminRole);
        roles.add(testRole);
        users.setRoles(roles);
        usersRepository.saveAndFlush(users);
}
```

Records are inserted in the below one

[image: users]

[image: role]

Entry added with uuid but name not saved.

[image: users_role]

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out the meaning of the annotation '@ManyToMany', use '@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}'  instead of yours.